# codefights isSubTress only one hide test case can not pass

Tags: javascript

Given two binary trees t1 and t2, determine whether the second tree is a subtree of the first tree. A subtree for vertex v in a binary tree t is a tree consisting of v and all its descendants in t. Determine whether or not there is a vertex v (possibly none) in tree t1 such that a subtree for vertex v (possibly empty) in t1 equals t2.

```
    //
    // Definition for binary tree:
    // function Tree(x) {
    //   this.value = x;
    //   this.left = null;
    //   this.right = null;
    // }
    function isSubtree(t1, t2) {

      function findroot(t1,t2){
        if(t2==null){
          return true;
        }else if(t1==null){
          if(t2==null){
            return true;
          }else{
            return false;
          }
        }else if((
            t1.value == t2.value && machedTree(t1,t2)) || findroot(t1.left,t2) || findroot(t1.right,t2)){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false
        }
      }
      function machedTree(t1,t2){
        if((t1 == null && t2 == null)
          &&(t1 == null && t2==null)){
          return true;
        }else if( t2 == null ||
          ((t1 != null && t2!=null)
            && machedTree(t1.left,t2.left)
            &&t1.value == t2.value
            &&machedTree(t1.right,t2.right))){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }

      }
      return findroot(t1,t2)
    }
```

Has only one hide test case can not pass. do you have any idea where is wrong for the code

Answer (score 0):

function isSubtree(t1, t2) {

```
      function findroot(t1,t2){
        if(t2==null){
          return true;
        }else if(t1==null){
          return false;
        }else if((
            t1.value == t2.value && machedTree(t1,t2)) || findroot(t1.left,t2) || findroot(t1.right,t2)){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false
        }
      }
      function machedTree(t1,t2){
        if(t1==null && t2 == null){
          return true;
        }
        else if((t2 != null && t1 != null)
          && machedTree(t1.left,t2.left)
          && (t1.value === t2.value)
          &&machedTree(t1.right,t2.right)){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }

      }
      return findroot(t1,t2)
    }
```